# What does " 万寿一 " and " つうさん " mean?

Tags: translation

In a telephone register, 万寿一 was behind a surname. What does 万寿一 mean when written behind a surname?

And second, I came across this sentence.

> つうさんのこと未だ引きずって、マイナス思考が激しいね。

What does つうさん mean? Is 'tsu' a syllable (mora) and is san a suffix in this case?

Comment: Without context, I have to assume つうさん is 通算, meaning *total*.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but 万寿一 seems a given name ますいち.

Comment: Is the sentence with つうさん supposed to be from the telephone register as well, or is it from somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

「万寿一」 should be a given name if it was placed behind a surname.

It would be read 「ますいち」 and the characters mean literally "10,000 - felicitations - one".  It is not a regular word, so it does not really have a clear meaning.

Regarding the reading, it may actually turn out to be totally different.  That is because the Japanese civil laws allow kanji used in a baby name to be read ***anyway*** you want when you register it.

Onto 「つうさん」...

Without context, It is just impossible to tell what it means.  There is the word [通算]{つうさん} meaning "final aggregate" but that is not the kind of word one would write in hiragana.

It is possible that it is a nickname.  In any case, you would need to provide the context.

EDIT: Now that we have some context and it sure would be someone's nickname.  Many nicknames include さん、ちゃん、くん, etc at the end.